# UIScrollView / Adding xibs to it

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, xib

I am trying to create a scroll view and add 2 xib screens (SVPage1.xib and SVPage2.xib) to it so that I can flip through both screens.

I created scrollview and Page Control object.

This is what I have in .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SVPage1" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *mainView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:mainView];

    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 2;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    NSArray *subviewArray2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SVPage2" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *mainView2 = [subviewArray2 objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:mainView2];

    //Set the content size of our scrollview according to the total width of our imageView objects.
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(mainView.frame.size.width * 3, mainView2.frame.size.height);
}

#pragma mark - UIScrollView Delegate
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    // Update the page when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
}
```

I believe when I load the second xib file I load it over the first one.

When I run the program I see second xib file on the screen and when I flip through the other pages they are blank. I think I am doing something horribly wrong trying to add the second .xib...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, when you create a view, it's origin is set to (0, 0). I think you are just forgetting to set the origin point of the second view's frame to your variable

```
mainView2.frame = frame;
```